# update multiple Records at a time using checkbox laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, bulkupdate

I want to update multiple records statuses or delete.

Status is: accept, reject, pending.

so want to give checkbox to the user for select multiple records and dropdown for choose status want to update records at a time,

and also want to give the delete option on the dropdown to delete mass records at a time

Comment: please add your code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered a similar question few days back. Look [Update status of each dynamic row using checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58679443/update-status-of-each-dynamic-row-using-checkbox).

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: its working Good but if i select accept in select option so all row status update to accept, Same for reject how to do that

Answer (score 1):

```
public function updateRecords(Request $request) {
   $recordIds = $request->get('recordIds');
   $newStatus = $request->get('newStatus');
   RecordModel::whereIn('id', $recordIds)->update(['status' => $newStatus]);
}
```

```
public function deleteRecords(Request $request) {
   $recordIds = $request->get('recordIds');
   RecordModel::whereIn('id', $recordIds)->delete();
}
```

Comment: your ```deleteRecords function``` working fine but the ```updateRecords``` not working any other idea for that